# Inception V3 fine tuning

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am not from cs background and I am trying to create a classifier in which I feed images containing disease and images without disease. I was trying to do fine tuning using inception v3 for this. Unfortunately all the examples for fine tuning are done for vgg-16 and they stop by saying inception v3 is trained similarly in almost all tutorials. I am using keras with tensorflow back-end. Everyone tells me to truncate the final softmax layer of inception and add two layers and do the fine tuning.I do not know how to add layer in inception also I am going to store my data in 2 folders this is also creating a headache for me as some tutorials load cifar database while others use directories and I'm uncomfortable with this too. Can anyone provide me with some inputs?

**train.py**

```py
import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras import backend as K
from keras import __version__
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, AveragePooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD


IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 299, 299 #fixed size for InceptionV3
NB_EPOCHS = 3
BAT_SIZE = 32
FC_SIZE = 1024
#NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE = 172


def get_nb_files(directory):
    """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        return 0
    cnt = 0
    for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for dr in dirs:
            cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
    return cnt


def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
    """Freeze all layers and compile the model"""
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
    """Add last layer to the convnet

    Args:
        base_model: keras model excluding top
        nb_classes: # of classes

    Returns:
        new keras model with last layer
    """
    x = base_model.output
    x = AveragePooling2D((8, 8), border_mode='valid', name='avg_pool')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
    return model

"""
def setup_to_finetune(model):
    Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top layers.

    note: NB_IV3_LAYERS corresponds to the top 2 inception blocks in the inceptionv3 arch

    Args:
        model: keras model

    for layer in model.layers[:NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE]:
        layer.trainable = False
    for layer in model.layers[NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE:]:
        layer.trainable = True
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
"""

def train(args):
    """Use transfer learning and fine-tuning to train a network on a new dataset"""
    train_img = 'training_set/' 
    validation_img = 'test_set/'
    nb_epoch = int(args.nb_epoch)
    nb_train_samples = get_nb_files(train_img)
    nb_classes = len(glob.glob(train_img + "/*"))
    # data prep
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_img,
        target_size=(299, 299),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_img,
        target_size=(299, 299),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
    if(K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'):
        input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
    else:
        input_tensor = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))

    # setup model
    base_model = InceptionV3(input_tensor = input_tensor,weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape=(IM_HEIGHT,IM_WIDTH,3)) #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
    model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)

    # transfer learning
    setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)



    history_tl = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                     samples_per_epoch=320,
                                     nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                                     validation_data=validation_generator,
                                     nb_val_samples=64) 
    model.save(args.output_model_file)
    if args.plot:
        plot_training(history_tl)


def plot_training(history):
    acc = history.history['acc']
    val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
    loss = history.history['loss']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
    epochs = range(len(acc))

    plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r.')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r')
    plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
    plt.savefig('accuracy.png')

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r.')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r-')
    plt.title('Training and validation loss')
    plt.savefig('loss.png')


if __name__=="__main__":            
    a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    a.add_argument("--nb_epoch", default=NB_EPOCHS)
    a.add_argument("--batch_size", default=BAT_SIZE)
    a.add_argument("--plot", action="store_true")
    a.add_argument("--output_model_file", default="inceptionv3-ft.model")
    args = a.parse_args()

    train(args)
```

**predictions.py**

```py
    import sys
    import argparse
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    import requests
    from io import BytesIO
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from keras.preprocessing import image
    from keras.models import load_model
    from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input


    target_size = (299, 299) #fixed size for InceptionV3 architecture


    def predict(model, img, target_size):
        """Run model prediction on image
        Args:
            model: keras model
            img: PIL format image
            target_size: (w,h) tuple
        Returns:
            list of predicted labels and their probabilities 
        """
        if img.size != target_size:
            img = img.resize(target_size)

        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        preds = model.predict(x)
        return preds[0]


    def plot_preds(image, preds):
        """Displays image and the top-n predicted probabilities in a bar graph
        Args:
            image: PIL image
            preds: list of predicted labels and their probabilities
        """



        plt.figure()
        labels = (" NO DR", "DR")
        plt.barh([0, 1], preds, alpha=0.5)
        plt.yticks([0, 1], labels)
        plt.xlabel('Probability')
        plt.xlim(0,1.01)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig('out.png')


    if __name__=="__main__":
        a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        a.add_argument("--image", help="path to image")
        a.add_argument("--image_url", help="url to image")
        a.add_argument("--model")
        args = a.parse_args()

        if args.image is None and args.image_url is None:
            a.print_help()
            sys.exit(1)

        model = load_model(args.model)
        if args.image is not None:
            img = Image.open(args.image)
            preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
            plot_preds(img, preds)

        if args.image_url is not None:
            response = requests.get(args.image_url)
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
            preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
            plot_preds(img, preds)
```

Finally I will pass an image via arguments and get a result in the form of a PNG file.

Comment: please add the code you have written so far. We'll try to answer your question from that.

Comment: This is the code i passed around 3000 images 1500 for each diseased and non-diseased and then used around 400 images for validation but I am getting a low accuracy of 58% with a loss of .60.Also, I did data augmentation separately and passed it.
Epochs 50 with batch size of 32

Comment: I updated the post with code @ldavid

Comment: This code has no train procedure (which was your original question). Which vgg16 tutorial are you basing your work?

Comment: Really sorry I accidentally posted my predict script instead of my learning script I have updated the code sorry for creating an inconvenience @ldavid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have multiple unrelated questions, but pretty much all of them are already answered in stackoverflow. I'll try to compile some information to give you some direction:

> i feed images containing disease and images without disease [...] Everyone tells me to truncate the final softmax layer of inception and add two layers and do the fine tuning

I believe it's a little cleaner to load the model without its "top" dense layers (`softmax` included), and re-add the top layers yourself:

```py
# This will load inception without its top dense layers (there's only 2).
model = InceptionV3(..., weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = model.output
# Re-add the layers here, with new weights.
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=x)
```

Notice that you should NOT use both `GlobalAveragePooling2D` and `Flatten` together, as you are doing in your train script.

In case you use `VGG16`, the architecture is a little different:

```py
model = VGG16(..., weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = model.output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
```

*Note: you might want to change these `4096`. They seem a little high for only 2 classes.*

> also I am going to store my data in 2 folders this is also creating a headache for me as some tutorials load cifar database while others use directories and I'm uncomfortable with this too.

`cifar` database in keras is a toy example. A debugging start to make sure everything else is running smoothly. This is why it can be loaded directly into the main memory.
Real datasets need to be stored into disk.
If they are contained in sub-foders named after their labels, such as this:

```
train/
  |-label_a/
  |-label_b/
  ...
  |-label_z/
valid/
  |-label_a/
  |-label_b/
  ...
  |-label_z/
```

Then there's a helper for you that can automatically load these images and associate them with their correct labels:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
# or from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

train_dir = '/datasets/problem/train/'
valid_dir = '/datasets/problem/valid/'

g = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train = g.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                              target_size=(256, 256),
                              batch_size=32,
                              shuffle=True)
valid = g.flow_from_directory(valid_dir,
                              target_size=(256, 256),
                              batch_size=32,
                              shuffle=True)
```

*Note: this seems to be the case for your train script.*

If your dataset is not aranged such as this, then you need to implement a [`Sequence`](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) that's capable of loading the data for you and associate it with the appropriate labels.

Comment: thankyou so much I am starting to get hang of it now. I will try to implement it in VGG-16 as it seems more comprehensible to me and I will return to you with my doubts once that is cleared up I will proceed with inception V3 model.I'm really happy now :)

Comment: Please search for old questions or ask new ones. I'll answer them if I can.